# Tooltip plugin for portfolio website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugin

I am writing my own tooltip plugin for my portfolio website that I am currently working on.  It works rather well, however, I feel that there is a lot I could improve.  This is one of my bigger jQuery plugins that I have written.

```
(function($) {

// Used as a template for addTooltip()
var tooltipDefaults = {
    'class': null,
    'showOn': 'mouseenter',
    'hideOn': 'mouseleave',
    'direction': 'top',
    'offset': null
}

// Store generated IDs to avoid conflicting IDs
var tooltipIds = new Array();

// Keep track of displayed popups
var displayedTooltips = new Array();

function generateUniqueId()
{
    var id;

    do {
        id = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    } while ($.inArray(id, tooltipIds) !== -1);

    tooltipIds.push(id);
    return id;
}

function getUniqueId(id)
{
    return parseInt(id.substr(0, 5));
}

function isUniqueId(id)
{
    return !NaN(getUniqueId(id));
}

function removeUniqueId(id)
{
        var id = getUniqueId(id);

        var idIndex = $.inArray(id, tooltipIds);

        if (idIndex !== -1) {
            tooltipIds.splice(idIndex);
        }
}

$.fn.displayTooltip = function()
{
    var element = $(this);
    var tooltip = $('#' + element.attr('data-tooltip-id'));
    var config = element.data('config');

    var offset = element.offset();

    var left;   
    var top;

    switch (config.direction) {
        case 'left':
            top = offset.top + "px";
            left = offset.left - tooltip.outerWidth() - config.offset + "px";
            break;
        case 'top':
            top = offset.top - element.outerHeight() - config.offset + "px";
            left = offset.left + ((element.outerWidth() / 2) - (tooltip.outerWidth() / 2)) + "px";
            break;
        case 'right':
            top = offset.top + "px";
            left = offset.left + element.outerWidth() + config.offset + "px";
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            top = offset.top + element.outerHeight() + config.offset + "px";
            left = offset.left + ((element.outerWidth() / 2) - (tooltip.outerWidth() / 2)) + "px";
            break;
    }

    tooltip.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': left,
        'top': top,
        'z-index': 5000
    });

    if (element.isTooltipDisplayed()) {
        return;
    }

    tooltip.show();
    displayedTooltips.push(element.attr('id'));
}

$.fn.hideTooltip = function()
{
    var element = $(this);

    var idIndex = $.inArray(element.attr('id'), displayedTooltips);

    if (idIndex !== -1) {
        displayedTooltips.splice(idIndex);
    }

    $('#' + element.attr('data-tooltip-id')).hide();
}

$.fn.addTooltip = function(content, params)
{
    var config = $.extend(tooltipDefaults, params);

    return this.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        // If the element already has a tooltip change the content inside of it
        if (element.hasTooltip()) {
            $('#' + element.attr('data-tooltip-id')).html(content);
            return;
        }

        var tooltipId = (element.is('[id]') ? element.attr('id') : generateUniqueId()) + '-tooltip';
        element.attr('data-tooltip-id', tooltipId);

        var tooltip = $('<div>', {
            id: tooltipId,
            role: 'tooltip',
            class: config.class
        }).html(content);

        $('body').append(tooltip);

        /**
         * If showOn and hideOn are the same events bind a toggle
         * listener else bind the individual listeners
         */
        if (config.showOn === config.hideOn) {
            element.on(config.showOn, function() {
                if (!element.isTooltipDisplayed()) {
                    element.displayTooltip();
                } else {
                    element.hideTooltip();
                }
            });
        } else {
            element.on(config.showOn, function() {
                element.displayTooltip();
            }).on(config.hideOn, function() {
                element.hideTooltip();
            });
        }

        // Store config for other functions use
        element.data('config', config);

        // Saftey check incase the element recieved focus from the code running above
        element.hideTooltip();
    });
}

$.fn.hasTooltip = function()
{
    return $(this).is('[data-tooltip-id]');
}

$.fn.isTooltipDisplayed = function()
{
    var element = $(this);

    if (!element.hasTooltip()) {
        return false;
    }

    return ($.inArray(element.attr('id'), displayedTooltips) === -1) ? false : true;
}

$.fn.removeTooltip= function()
{
    return this.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var tooltipId = element.attr('data-tooltip-id');
        var config = element.data('config');

        $('#' + tooltipId).remove();

        if (isUniqueId(tooltpId)) {
            removeUniqueId(tooltipId);
        }

        element.removeAttr('data-tooltip-id');

        if (config.showOn === config.hideOn) {
            element.off(config.showOn);
        } else {
            element.off(config.showOn);
            element.off(config.hideOn);
        }

        element.removeData('config');
    });
}

// Reposition tooltip on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (displayedTooltips.length < 1) {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < displayedTooltips.length; i++) {
        $('#' + displayedTooltips[i]).displayTooltip();
        console.log(displayedTooltips);
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: `new Array()` -> `[]`

Comment: `if (element.isTooltipDisplayed()) { return; }` could probably called before all left & top calculations...

Comment: 1.this is not good jquery plugin api style conversion.  your plugin should only has one namespace. 2. not use utility in jQuery(like $.inArray), the performance is too slow

Comment: check this performance table [jspref](http://jsperf.com/jquery-inarray-vs-underscore-indexof/24)

Comment: @caoglish `indexOf()`

Answer (score 1):

From a once over:

- There seems to be a ton of overkill with regards to `id`, since the user will never look at the id of a tooltip, you can simply use:

  ```
  function generateUniqueId()
  {
    var id = generateUniqueId.id = ( generateUniqueId.id || 0) + 1;
    tooltipIds.push(id);
    return id;
  }
  ```

  on the whole I would review the code and simplify how id's work.
- Namespaces; @caoglish is right, your approach is wrong. jQuery plugin style would be 1 function `tooltip` on which you can call then `create`, `show`, `hide` etc.
- In `removeUniqueId` you simply use `id = getUniqueId(id);` ( drop the `var` ), since you already have the `id` as a parameter
- As @Charlie mentioned; `var tooltipIds = new Array();` -> `var tooltipIds = [];`
- In `removeTooltip` you have a bug in `(isUniqueId(tooltpId)) {` , you meant to use `tooltipId`
- You would have caught this if you added `"use strict";` right after `(function($) {` (this activates strict mode)
- I really like the way you use `config` in `displayTooltip`
- `console.log()` does not belong in production code

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will be sure to make these changes. Can you possibly explain to me how that generateUniqueId method works?

Comment: I am using the function to store the value of `id` and I just keep adding 1 so that the value is unique.

Comment: Alright, also is it really ideal to only use one namespace. It just seems cluttered to toss everything into one namespace. Or is there a design pattern that could make something like that better?

Comment: I will agree that it might be more cluttered for the author, but the convenience of the user comes first ;)

Comment: I just rewrote the whole plugin to an OOP approach. I also made the changes you suggested and the whole ID system is now out. I dropped about 80 lines of code. How much better is this than the previous one and are there still areas to be improved? If you wouldn't mind taking a look that is.